# Apikey is invalid for POST, but valid for GET requests?

Tags: kotlin, google-api, http-headers, okhttp

Try to get any response from public api (Google translate).
Have 403 "The request is missing a valid API key" in POST calls, but at the same moment success response from GET calls.

```
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    // POST DETECT
    val mediaType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".toMediaTypeOrNull()
    val body = "q=English%20is%20hard%2C%20but%20detectably%20so".toRequestBody(mediaType)
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("$urlPrefix/detect")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip")
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key",  apiKey)
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", apiHost)
        .build()

    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
    println("POST: " + response.body!!.string())

    // GET LANGUAGES
    val reqGet = Request.Builder()
        .url("$urlPrefix/languages")
        .get()
        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/gzip")
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key",  apiKey)
        .addHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host", apiHost)
        .build()

    val respGet = client.newCall(reqGet).execute()
    println("GET: " + respGet.body!!.string())
```

Should i use smth instead of okhttp3:okhttp:4.12.0 or how to fix it?

Probably apiKey is correct, because after changed it in GET||POST calls, response was:

```
"{"message":"You are not subscribed to this API."}"
```

Response POST:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Request headers:

```
{
  "host": "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
  "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-654f490d-7f0a4fed6376983b7736b3d4",
  "x-forwarded-port": "443",
  "x-forwarded-proto": "https",
  "content-length": "48",
  "x-forwarded-for": "62.217.189.77",
  "user-agent": "okhttp/4.12.0",
  "x-rapidapi-host": "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
  "accept-encoding": "application/gzip"
}
```